# How to write a subquery within a SELECT query MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have been trying to figure out how to incorporate a subquery into my working SELECT query. Below is my query that is grabbing the project name from the projects table and through a left join I am grabbing the date within the project_work table. The project_id is a foriegn key connecting to the projects table(id).

```
SELECT projects.Project_Name, project_work.Completed_Date 
FROM projects LEFT JOIN project_work ON projects.id=project_work.project_id
```

The query above prints out the following:

```
+---------------+---------------+
| Project Name  | Completed Date|
+------+--------+---------+------
| John Smith    |  2020-10-06   |
+------+--------+---------+------
| John Smith    |  2020-10-09   |
+------+--------+---------+------
| John Smith    |  2020-10-08   |
+------+--------+---------+------
| Jane Doe      |  2020-10-12   |
+------+--------+---------+------
| Jane Doe      |  2020-10-04   |
+------+--------+---------+------
```

I want my subquery to look at each date belonging to the same project name and only show the most recent date:

```
+---------------+---------------+
| Project Name  | Completed Date|
+------+--------+---------+------
| John Smith    |  2020-10-09   |
+------+--------+---------+------
| Jane Doe      |  2020-10-12   |
+------+--------+---------+------
```

I was attempting to add something like the following, but kept getting syntax errors. Clearly this isn't correct. Can someone explain to me the correct way to use a subquery for this case?

```
WHERE projects.id=project_work.project_id 
SELECT MAX(project_work.Completed_Date) 
FROM project_work 
ORDER BY project_work.Completed_Date ASC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one possibility

```
SELECT 
    projects.Project_Name, project_work.Completed_Date
FROM
    projects
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        project_id, MAX(project_work.Completed_Date)
    FROM
        project_work
    GROUP BY project_id) ON projects.id = project_work.project_id;
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    projects.Project_Name, project_work.Completed_Date
FROM
    projects
        LEFT JOIN
    project_work ON projects.id = project_work.project_id
WHERE
    project_work.Completed_Date = (SELECT 
            MAX(Completed_Date)
        FROM
            Completed_Date
        WHERE
            project_id = projects.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery for this, just:

```
SELECT projects.Project_Name, MAX(project_work.Completed_Date)
FROM projects
LEFT JOIN project_work ON projects.id=project_work.project_id
GROUP BY projects.Project_Name
```